# How to speed up classes and objects in python, related to move generation for a chess engine

Tags: performance, python-chess

I’m in the beginnings of creating a chess engine written in python and I was wondering of ways to improve the move generation part. Generating pseudo-legal moves I can do about 30/40 K moves/s on my computer and with the slow move validation I have written that drops down to about 11 K moves/s but I am in the midst of writing a better version.

I use a 1D array of two character strings (though my previous version using 2D arrays was faster) and I have made both a Move and a Board State class. I have already implemented slots and I was looking for a way to speed up the classes even more. I have tried numba but I could not get it to work as I am passing a Board State obj in the Move class constructor and so the code did not compile with numba. Are there any other libraries that can be used in this case. The code can be found here: https://github.com/FedericoSaitta/Chess/tree/master/Files

- I should also mention that I am running the engine script on a GUI in pygame handled by the main.py file.

Here are the constructors for my two classes:

class GameState:
**slots** = ('board', 'white_to_move', 'moveLog', 'w_l_c', 'b_l_c',
'w_r_c', 'b_r_c', 'white_king_loc', 'black_king_loc',
'check_mate', 'stale_mate', 'white_en_passant_sq', 'black_en_passant_sq')

```
def __init__(self):

    self.board = [  # Switching to a 1D board representation    # Left right is +/- 1 and up               and down is +/- 8
        'bR', 'bN', 'bB', 'bQ', 'bK', 'bB', 'bN', 'bR',  # 0 to 7
        'bP', 'bP', 'bP', 'bP', 'bP', 'bP', 'bP', 'bP',  # 8 to 15
        '--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--',  # 16 to 23
        '--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--',  # 24 to 31
        '--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--',  # 32 to 39
        '--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--',  # 40 to 47
        'wP', 'wP', 'wP', 'wP', 'wP', 'wP', 'wP', 'wP',  # 48 to 55
        'wR', 'wN', 'wB', 'wQ', 'wK', 'wB', 'wN', 'wR']  # 56 to 63

    self.white_to_move = True
    self.moveLog = []

    self.w_l_c, self.b_l_c = True, True  # Castling rights for white and black
    self.w_r_c, self.b_r_c = True, True

    self.white_king_loc = (60)  # Make sure to change these once you change to a new board
    self.black_king_loc = (4)
    self.check_mate, self.stale_mate = False, False

    self.white_en_passant_sq, self.black_en_passant_sq = (None, None), (None, None)
```

And
class Move:

```
__slots__ = ('start_ind', 'end_ind', 'move_ID',
             'piece_moved', 'piece_captured', 'castle_move', 'en_passant')


def __init__(self, start_sq, end_sq, board, castle_move=False, en_passant=False):

    self.start_ind = start_sq  
    self.end_ind = end_sq  

    self.move_ID = self.start_ind * 100 + self.end_ind
    self.piece_moved = board[self.start_ind]

    self.piece_captured = board[self.end_ind]

    self.castle_move = castle_move
    self.en_passant = en_passant
```

Comment: Python is clearly not suited for such computations. In fact Python shine for high-level glue code and scripting, not intensive computing, mainly because of the interpreter.

Comment: Numba is not suited for string computing. In fact, string are slow and should be avoided anyway (whatever the language used). Numba is fast for Numpy array operations and integer/floating-point based computations. If you use a Numpy array containing integers it should be better. Cython can also help (and can possibly generate a faster code).

Comment: Also please note that OOP make things complicated. Simple basic functions make things simpler for both Cython and Numba. OOP can also make things slower in some cases, even in native languages like C++.

Comment: I have just made the switch from 1D string array to 1D arrays of ints and gained about 10 % speed increase. Do you reckon switching out of OOP would make that much of a difference? Because it would certainly decrease the code readability and I have tested out configuarations were the board is stored as a python list not as an object of my class and that did not seem to have any effect on the speed.

Comment: This is frequent in my job to get a big speed up by replacing OOP code with non-OOP one, if the new code is *SIMD-friendly* (this point is the most critical one). OOP code tends not to be SIMD friendly because of the memory layout of data structure. Data-oriented design helps to mitigate the cost of OOP but there are many optimisation that are simply not possible on full OOP codes. OOP is fine for modules, but not for fine-grained object computations (unless one do not care about performance).

Comment: CPython lists are just objects like user objects (though they are implemented in the interpreter itself). They are generally not very efficient compared to what a native code can achieve. Operations on them are made using the (slow) interpreted and they are not strongly typed (nor SIMD friendly).